# Android: Create a new intent with a button from a GridView (GridView with Navigation buttons)

Tags: android, gridview, android-intent, navigation

I have created a class of type BaseAdapter that is populated with buttons - when you click on a button I want to load a new intent. This has proven difficult on two levels:

1. You cannot associate the event with the button (one that creates a new intent) inside the Adapter. This is why I send the Buttons as an array to my Adapter (this solution works, but it is messy)
2. Even though my buttons are created inside the same Activity - they cannot create a new intent from that Activity. The exeption is so great that I have not even gotten a try...catch statement to work.

I have tried reflection, creating the buttons inside the activity and passing them through, passing the context (to call context.startIntent(...))

My question: can someone show me how to create a ButtonAdapter where each button creates a new Intent - even of the same type as the original Activity?

**UPDATE**: Here is the code because I am getting answers from people who think I am struggling with onClickListeners:

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context _context;
    private Button[] _button;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c, Button[] buttons)
    {
        _context = c;  
        _button = buttons;
    }

    // Total number of things contained within the adapter  
    public int getCount()
    {  
        return _button.length;  
    }  

    // Require for structure, not really used in my code.  
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {  
        return _button[position];  
    }  

    // Require for structure, not really used in my code. Can  
    // be used to get the id of an item in the adapter for  
    // manual control.  
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {  
        return position;  
    }  

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {          
        _button[position].setId(position);  
        return _button[position];  
    }
}
```

---------------
The Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private GridView _gv;
    private TextView _heading;       
    private ButtonAdapter _adapter;

    public void LoadActivity(String heading)
    {
        try
        {
            Itent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Level", "NextPage");
            intent.putExtra("Heading", heading);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("Error LoadActivity: %s", ex.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }    

    private void createButtonsAdapter(Button _button[])
    {
        _buttonadapter = new ButtonAdapter(getApplicationContext(), _button);
        _gv.setAdapter(_adapter);  
    }         

    private void setupButtons()
    {
        Button[] _buttons = new Button[2];
        String names[] = new String[]{"Button1","Button2"};

        for (int i = 0; i &lt; 2; i++)
        {
            _buttons[i] = new Button(this);
            _buttons[i].setText(names[i]);
            _buttons[i].setTag(names[i]);

           _buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
           {
               public void onClick(View arg0)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       LoadActivity(((Button)arg0).getTag().toString());
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("Error button.onClick: %s", ex.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
        }
        createButtonsAdapter(_buttons);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        _heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_heading);                      

        Bundle params = getIntent().getExtras();                

        if (params == null)
        {
            setupButtons();    
        }  
        else if (params.containsKey("Level"))
        {
            _heading.setText(params.getString("Heading"));
            if (params.getString("Level").equals("NextPage"))
            {
                //code not here yet
            }
            else if (params.getString("Level").equals("Chapters"))
            {
                //future code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Excuse the bold and caps but I have had enough silly answers to warrent this:
**I HAVE TRIED PUTTING THE ONCLICKLISTENER INSIDE THE GRIDVIEW AND IT DOES NOT WORK EITHER**
You cannout load an activity from a class outside that activity, even if you pass the context as a parameter. That is why I have resorted to this method, which completely bombs android, even though I have try catch statements.

Please try give me a solution in the form of a correction to my code, other code, or a tutorial that achieves what I want here. I know how to do a button adapter properly, it is the act of loading an Intent that has forced me to implement it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I am answering my own question:
http://bottlecapnet.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-buttons-have-no-place-inside.html

I will just have to style TextViews as I want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following,

1. Using a common onClick listner for all the buttons in your grid view
2. Set tag for all the butons in the getView func. of adapter.
3. Use the tag Object to decide on the intent to fire from the onClick listener.

I hope it helps..

Comment: Please see my comment on the previous "solution." This is not an easy answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can easily manipulate your buttons created in your class extending Base adapter. In the getView method .... if you have button b.. then do it as follows

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick()
    {
        // Do your stuff here ... 
    }
});
```

and if you want to start another activity on Click of this button then you need to pass the calling context to this adapter.

Comment: Please try your solutions before submitting an answer. I know how to set an onClickListener. I want a Button in a GridView that starts a new activity. I know how to create button events. I know how to create GridViews and Adapters. I know how to start new Activities with Intents. I want to know how to put these together.